# How to visualize java complex collection objects with multiple levels down in diagrams

Tags: java

How to visualize java collection objects in diagrams? I work better with pictures and videos than words and books.

If a map has key as string and list as value.
The above list has another list of custom objects.
The custom object has another list.

These types of scenarios coming in real-world projects quite often.
How to picture and imagine these types of scenarios to move forward with coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine such an example. Each of your friends has a list of countries that he or she has visited.

[image]

Key is `String` name, value is `List<Country>`.

```
Map countriesVisited = new HashMap<String, List<Country>>();
```

Each country has a number of cities that your friend has visited. For instance, Li has visited Kyiv, Odesa, and Lviv in Ukraine. And in Kyiv, he visited the 3 places of interest:

[image]

The code is the following. Play with it to see how it works:

```
public class Travellers {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Country countryUkraine = new Country("Ukraine");
        
        Map countriesVisited = new HashMap<String, List<Country>>();
        countriesVisited.put("George", Arrays.asList(
                new Country("Japan"), new Country("Brazil"), new Country("Poland"), 
                new Country("Croatia"), new Country("Nigeria"), new Country("Laos"), 
                new Country("Germany")
        ));
        countriesVisited.put("Li", Arrays.asList(
                new Country("Argentina"), countryUkraine, new Country("Italy"), 
                new Country("Great Britain"), new Country("Nepal")
        ));
        countriesVisited.put("Keith", Arrays.asList(
                new Country("Egypt"), new Country("Greece"), new Country("Lebanon"), 
                new Country("Marocco"), new Country("Saudi Arabia"), new Country("Kuwait")
        ));
        countriesVisited.put("Jenny", Arrays.asList(
                new Country("Norway"), new Country("Canada"), new Country("Russia"), 
                new Country("Antarctica"), new Country("Finland")
        ));
        
        City cityKyiv = new City("Kyiv");
        countryUkraine.setCities(Arrays.asList(
                cityKyiv, new City("Odesa"), new City("Lviv")));
        Place placeKyiv1 = new Place("Lavra");
        Place placeKyiv2 = new Place("St Andrew’s Church");
        Place placeKyiv3 = new Place("Museum of Folk Architecture");
        cityKyiv.setPlaces(Arrays.asList(placeKyiv1, placeKyiv2, placeKyiv3));
        
        System.out.println("Countries visited by George: " + countriesVisited.get("George"));
        System.out.println("Countries visited by Li: " + countriesVisited.get("Li"));
        System.out.println("Countries visited by Keith: " + countriesVisited.get("Keith"));
        System.out.println("Countries visited by Jenny: " + countriesVisited.get("Jenny"));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Cities visited by Li in Ukraine: " + countryUkraine.getCities());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Places visited by Li in Kyiv: " + cityKyiv.getPlaces());
    }
}

class Country {
    String name;
    List<City> cities;

    Country(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    void setCities(List<City> cities) {
        this.cities = cities;
    }
    
    List<City> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }
    
    @Override public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

class City {
    String name;
    List<Place> places;
    
    City(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    void setPlaces(List<Place> places) {
        this.places = places;
    }
    
    List<Place> getPlaces() {
        return places;
    }
    
    @Override public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

class Place {
    String name;
    int rating;
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
    Image img;
    
    Place(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    @Override public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very useful practical life example and way of thinking complex objects. Thank you

Comment: How to correlate this example to real world scenario with java objects which does not have real meaning when we look at them like InvoiceData is key having InvoiceDataList as value and InvoiceData list has say 3 elements. Each element has say field called items when called getter on items returns invoiceItemData custom object which the InvoiceNumber which i need to set based on database execute call

Comment: Have you already tried to correlate the example to your scenario?

Comment: that is where i am having hard time in correlating it as my mind works better with pictures than some raw data